# Consider the plane P in R-3 given by x-y-2z=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

I found the matrix A whose columns are a basis for P, A=[1,-1,-2] (vertical form).

Using that I was able to find the projection matrix:

P=$\frac{-1}{2} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 & 2 \\
           -1 & 1 &1 \\-2 &2 &-4 \end{array} \right)$

How would I find a vector e that is orthogonal to P and the projection matrix  $Q=\frac{ee^T}{e^Te}$ and how is that related to P?

Comment: Your $A =[1,-1,-2]^T$ is orthogonal to $P$, not contained in $P$.

Comment: Hint: What’s left when you subtract the orthogonal projection of a vector onto $P$ from the vector?